# JavaScript: Splitting and joining dates in mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm having a bit of difficulty comparing two dates that are entered in mm/dd/yyyy format. I have the following code written to try to convert them into yyyy-mm-dd format, and to display an error DIV if the start date is greater than the end date:

```
for(i=0; i<=9; i++)
{
   dateFrom+i = document.getElementById('projDateFrom'+i).value;
   dateTo+i = document.getElementById('projDateTo+i').value;
   dateFrom+i = dateFrom+i.split("/").reverse().join("-");
   dateTo+i = dateTo+i.split("/").reverse().join("-");
   if(dateFrom+i > dateTo+i)
   {
       document.getElementById('dateError').style.display = '';
       return false;
   }
```

When I enter the dates on my form in mm/dd/yyyy format, and I deliberately enter a projDateFrom that is greater than projDateTo, nothing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: `dateFrom+i`, `dateTo+i` what are these? Did you check console for errors?

Comment: `mm/dd/yyyy` is not the reverse of `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: @Matthew: I'm trying to convert mm/dd/yyyy into yyyy-mm-dd. Is that where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment.js is a fantastic date tool: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Here's a fiddle that will take just about any date format, convert it to a proper javascript object that is wrapped with many convenient date methods.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cFa2E/3

```
var diff = end.diff(start, 'days');
```

Where `end` is the date to compare against `start`

Comment: glad I was able to help